# Django-redactor: name 'widgets' is not defined

Tags: python, django, redactor

When I try to import `redactor.widgets` in my Django app I get the error from the title. In the python command line importing `redactor.widgets`doesn't produce any errors. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening? Everything runs in a virtualenv, I tried installing django-redactor using pip and manually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change the path in your app?

Comment: did you add redactor to your list of `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Yes, I added `redactor` to INSTALLED_APPS.